# React Native expo Stack Navigation Crashing the app for IOS only for --no-dev (Production) in after updating expo sdk from 45 to 48

Tags: expo, stack-navigator

SDK Version: 48
Platforms: IOS (Production Only)
React Native Stack Navigation.

I have recently updated my Expo app from SDK version 45 to 48, and encountered some Firebase-related issues. However, I was able to successfully resolve them and thought that all the issues had been resolved. However, when I attempted to run the app in --no-dev mode, I noticed that the app started crashing immediately after the splash screen, but only on iOS and not on Android.

Upon inspection, I discovered that the issue was caused by the React Native stack navigation. I was able to resolve the issue by removing the stack navigation. I am certain that I have imported “import ‘react-native-gesture-handler’;” in app.js, and that app.js is wrapped in a navigation container.

Please find my package.json file below.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bothrs/expo-mixpanel-analytics": "^2.0.3",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.7.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.11",
    "expo-application": "^5.1.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "^12.3.2",
    "expo-blur": "~12.2.2",
    "expo-camera": "^13.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "^14.2.1",
    "expo-facebook": "^12.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-core": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-haptics": "^12.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "^4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "^15.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.18.1",
    "expo-permissions": "^14.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.4",
    "expo-task-manager": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.16.3",
    "firebase": "9.10.0",
    "geofire": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-ios": "^4.1.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-accordion-list-view": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.4.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-circular-progress": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-text-ticker": "^1.14.0",
    "react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.12",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried different thing by reading breaking changes of sdk 48 but nothing worked for me